# Visual Studio 2017 Error initializing VroomJs.JsEngine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, visual-studio

My project uses Reactjs, and I use Visual Studio 2017. Recently I did an software update on VS 2017, but no code/config changes.

However, when I start my project locally in debug mode, I encountered below error:

```
No JavaScript engines were registered, falling back to a default config! It is recommended that you configure JavaScriptEngineSwitcher in your app. See https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki/Registration-of-JS-engines for more information.
Error initialising JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.V8JsEngineFactory: JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsEngineLoadException: During loading of V8JsEngine error has occurred. 
See more details:

Cannot load V8 interface assembly. Load failure information for v8-ia32.dll:
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\77655ce5\ca0bb6d0\assembly\dl3\300b733a\003cadac_c3f4d201\v8-ia32.dll: The specified module could not be found
C:\Code\project1\branches\apps\src\DotNet\COMP.project1.Web\v8-ia32.dll: The specified module could not be found
C:\Code\project1\branches\apps\src\DotNet\COMP.project1.Web\bin\v8-ia32.dll: The specified module could not be found ---> System.TypeLoadException: Cannot load V8 interface assembly. Load failure information for v8-ia32.dll:
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\77655ce5\ca0bb6d0\assembly\dl3\300b733a\003cadac_c3f4d201\v8-ia32.dll: The specified module could not be found
C:\Code\project1\branches\apps\src\DotNet\COMP.project1.Web\v8-ia32.dll: The specified module could not be found
C:\Code\project1\branches\apps\src\DotNet\COMP.project1.Web\bin\v8-ia32.dll: The specified module could not be found
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8Proxy.LoadNativeLibrary()
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8Proxy.LoadAssembly()
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8Proxy.GetAssembly()
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8Proxy.GetImplType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8Proxy.CreateImpl[T](Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8IsolateProxy.Create(String name, V8RuntimeConstraints constraints, Boolean enableDebugging, Int32 debugPort)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8Runtime..ctor(String name, V8RuntimeConstraints constraints, V8RuntimeFlags flags, Int32 debugPort)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine..ctor(V8Runtime runtime, String name, V8RuntimeConstraints constraints, V8ScriptEngineFlags flags, Int32 debugPort)
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.V8JsEngine..ctor(V8Settings settings)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.V8JsEngine..ctor(V8Settings settings)
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.V8JsEngineFactory.CreateEngine()
   at React.JavaScriptEngineFactory.GetFactory(JsEngineSwitcher jsEngineSwitcher, Boolean allowMsie)
Error initialising React.VroomJsEngine+Factory: JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsEngineLoadException: During loading of VroomJs JavaScript engine error has occurred.    
See more details:

The type initializer for 'VroomJs.JsEngine' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'VroomJs.JsEngine' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'VroomJsNative': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at VroomJs.JsEngine.js_set_object_marshal_type(JsObjectMarshalType objectMarshalType)
   at VroomJs.JsEngine..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at VroomJs.JsEngine..ctor(Int32 maxYoungSpace, Int32 maxOldSpace)
   at React.VroomJsEngine.<>c.<.cctor>b__23_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at React.VroomJsEngine.get_Engine()
   at React.VroomJsEngine..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at React.VroomJsEngine..ctor()
   at React.VroomJsEngine.Factory.CreateEngine()
   at React.JavaScriptEngineFactory.GetFactory(JsEngineSwitcher jsEngineSwitcher, Boolean allowMsie)
```

This error does not block me from running and testing the code.

Like I said, all I did recently was to update the VS 2017 software...I tried to do a wild search in the project for 'v8-ia32' but nothing found.

Comment: If you continue to have issues you could try another one that now supports .Net Standard: https://www.nuget.org/packages/V8.Net - But this issue seems to simply be that ClearScript cannot find the V8 native Dlls, and you are testing with a different engine (VroomJs?).

Answer (score 0):

To fix these errors I did the following:

1. Make sure you install the JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x86 and JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x64.
   (I didn't install JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x86)
2. According to https://reactjs.net/getting-started/aspnet.html
   edit the ReactConfig.cs, basically, I just added this

```
JsEngineSwitcher.Current.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName;
JsEngineSwitcher.Current.EngineFactories.AddV8();
```

3. Rebuild the project.